# Why does $\mathrm{exp}(i\mathbb R)$ produce the unit sphere of the 2-Norm?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, normed-spaces

I think I have a fairly good grasp of the basics of complex numbers, in particular of how the exponential function is defined.

Usually we define a scalar product on $\mathbb C$ viewed as an $\mathbb R$-vector space, which induces the structure of a normed vector space by means of the 2-norm ${\left \| \cdot \right \|}_2$.  However, we might have chosen any other norm.

But to define the exponential function, all we needed was the multiplication structure (and addition) on $\mathbb C$.  We never needed to choose the 2-norm! So

> why does the set of values $\mathrm{exp}(i\mathbb R)$ coincide with the sphere of the 2-norm, and not any other?

I do see that multiplication by $i$ is an isometry with respect to the $2$ norm, but it also is with respect to the other ones (e.g., if you rotate a square by 90 degrees you still get a square).

Comment: OT: It feels weird that this question occurred to me not until six years after my first semester of analysis which introduced these notions.

Comment: Your symmetry argument for the $1$-norm breaks down if you consider rotations that are not a multiple of $\frac \pi 2$.

Comment: Ah, that's true. but still: why would an infinite series of powers of $i\theta$ „care” about the 2-norm and converge to something on that sphere?

Comment: The basic, and easily proved, property of $\exp$ as defined by its power series is that $\exp (a+b)=\exp a \exp b$, which shows that $\exp$ is a group homomorphism from the additive group of $\mathbb{C}$ to its multiplicative group. Therefore the image of the imaginary axis must be a subgroup of that multiplicative group, which can only be bounded if it is a subgroup of the unit circle.